# Calculating sales on daily basis comparing the previous sales

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, join

How can I calculate sales on the basis of date comparing the previous, current, and upcoming dates?

```
order date  |   total qty
------------------------------
    02/01/2021  |   5   
    02/04/2021  |   10  
    02/06/2021  |   7
    02/08/2021  |   10
    02/10/2021  |   2
```

Comment: Divide "number of days since date X" by 7? You'll need to "sum your total over partition by bucket rows unbounded preceding" too by the looks of it

Comment: Oracle or Postgres? Those are two very different databases.

Comment: What interval does this "day bucket" represent? The difference to the current date? To some other date, like the beginning of the year? The beginning of the month? The beginning of the week?

Comment: @George Greg Do you only need the see the column "day bucket" in output? Or Will you need to add "day bucket" column in table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The interval is on weekly basis. Like from Feb 1 to Feb 7 it shows 1-7 days and from Feb 8 to Feb 14 it shows 8-14 days. It's in Postgres.

Comment: Can't you then just use the week number? e.g. `to_char(order_date, 'iyyy-iw')` and group by that?

Comment: @RakshaSaini I am adding the day bucket and cumulative frequency column, Table only contains orderdate and total qty.

Comment: @GeorgeGreg Which query you use to add the day bucket and cumulative column in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Your bucket column could be given by:

```
CONCAT(
  DATE_PART('day', AGE('2021-02-01', orderdate))*7+1,
  '-',
  (DATE_PART('day', AGE('2021-02-01', orderdate))+1)*7,
  ' days'
)
```

Your cumu total by:

```
SUM(total) OVER(PARTITION BY DATE_PART('day', AGE('2021-02-01', orderdate)) ORDER BY orderdate)
```

A sum has an implied "rows unbounded preceding" if it has an order by

I presume you're starting your report somewhere (eg your front end does `where orderdate > x` so it can supply the min date for the functions too. If it doesn't then you might benefit from a cte that calls the min orderdate